# iOS delegate method definition syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c

how do I understand the following syntax:

```
-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *) advertisementData:.....
```

so the method name is didDiscoverPeripheral, why central parameter is defined first?

Answer (score 2):

The method name is `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:`.

The first parameter tells you which manager discovered the peripheral. You'd otherwise have no idea who was talking to you. It's standard practice with delegate protocols in case you want to talk back.

Comment: ah, it's objective-c functions definition syntax is that f-ed up, I see now

Comment: Not really. Objective-C just uses named parameters. They're reasonably common across the scope of programming languages even if they don't tend to go with C-style syntax. Swift tries to split the difference with optionally named parameters and a convention that the first isn't named; that's what I'd consider f-ed up...

Comment: it's f-ed up for you since you are looking at them as a function.  Think more like message handlers. when someone calls you on the phone, you first see who is call you, then you get the message. Same for ObjC messages. You get who is telling you and the rest of the message. You can get viewContrllerDidFinish: which would just tell you the view controller. But the message is DidFinished.